# Check if data not exists in database before inserting it. SQL, NODE, EXPRESS SERVER

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have script that inserts data to the database and it works. I want to first  check if the record with the same data exist if not add to database. my script only inserts to database without checking it. please help how can i check the database before inserting data and then if no exist insert data.

NODE JS EXPRESS SERVER:

```
counter.post('/AddOrderStatus', function(req, res){
    const Status = 'PRINTING';
    const id = req.body.id;
    const nickname = req.body.nickname;
    const MsqlData = {nickname:nickname, status:Status, order_nr:id};
    OrderStatusMysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO orderdata SET ?', MsqlData, function (error) {
      if (error) {   return res.send('SEND TO ORDERSTATUS DATABASE ERROR');   }
         console.log('DATA SAVED TO ORDERSTATUS DATABASE');
         res.sendStatus(200);   
                }); 
            });
```

DATABASE CREATIION:

```
CREATE DATABASE order orderstatus;

CREATE TABLE `orderdata` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`nickname` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`order_nr` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `orderdata`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `orderdata`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: What is *same data*? Anyway, usually this kind of issues it is solved at database side by using `unique key`.

Answer (score 0):

can can use a unique Key to prevent duplications. The you can always use **INSERT** with **ON DUPLICATE KEY** to prevent dups.

```
INSERT INTO `orderdata` ( `nickname`, `status`, `order_nr`) 
 VALUES ( 'Bernd', '1', '123') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 status=status;
```

**SAMPLE**

```
CREATE TABLE `orderdata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nickname` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `order_nr` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uni_nickname` (`nickname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



mysql> INSERT INTO `orderdata` ( `nickname`, `status`, `order_nr`)
    -> VALUES
    -> ('Bernd', '1', '123')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -> status=status;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `orderdata` (`id`, `nickname`, `status`, `order_nr`) VALUES (1, 'Bernd', '1', '123') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status=status;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```